# Rails scope for joined table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, join, scope

I'm trying to build a scope for users, where owning a business.

The User got a role with a boolean flag, called "owner".

So I've added something like this, and tried several possibilities, but either I get an error or the selection is blank.

```
class User
  belongs_to :role

  scope :owner, -> { where(:role.owner) }
end
```

I can't find a solution...

I also tried to build selections like:

```
User.joins(:role).where(role: [owner: true])
```

or

```
User.joins(:role).where("roles.owner = true")
```

Answer (score 2):

Got it :)

```
scope :owners, -> {  joins(:role).where("owner = ?", true) }
```

Comment: You should be able to use `where(roles: { owner: true })`. Note that you have to use the table name (roles) instead of the relation name (role).